Stuck in proving this: If 2 quadratics have the same roots, then f(x)/g(x) = some real number constant
So I just randomly thought about this today and was thinking how I'd prove it. Intuitively I can think about how quadratics are products of 2 linear factors, $a(x-r)(x-s)$, where $r$, $s$ are real number roots and a is a real number constant. However, I don't recall the specific theorem I'd have to invoke when trying to formally prove it. Additionally, my question is mainly being stuck on my own attempt of proving it since once I can prove this one part of the proof, I pretty much complete the proof.
Ok so I start off with assuming:

the 2 functions being $f(x) = a_{1}x^{2} + a_{2}x + a_{3}$ and $g(x) = b_{1}x^{2} + b_{2}x + b_{3}$,
$a_{1} \neq 0 $ and $b_{1} \neq 0$ (just to avoid possibility of dealing with $f(x) = 0$ or $g(x) = 0$ and just dealing with practical quadratics)
The shared roots are $x_{0}$ and $x_{1}$

$(a_{1}x_{0}^{2} + a_{2}x_{0} = -a_{3})$
and $(b_{1}x_{0}^{2} + b_{2}x_{0} = -b_{3})$
$\implies$
$\frac{a_{1}x_{0}^{2} + a_{2}x_{0}}{b_{1}x_{0}^{2} + b_{2}x_{0}} = \frac{a_{3}}{b_{3}}$
$\iff$
$a_{1}x_{0}^{2} + a_{2}x_{0} = (\frac{a_{3}}{b_{3}})b_{1}x_{0}^{2} + (\frac{a_{3}}{b_{3}})b_{2}x_{0}$
Now if I can somehow prove that $a_{1} = (\frac{a_{3}}{b_{3}})b_{1}$ and $a_{2} = (\frac{a_{3}}{b_{3}})b_{2}$, then I can show $\frac{a_{1}}{b_{1}} = \frac{a_{2}}{b_{2}} = \frac{a_{3}}{b_{3}} = c \in \mathbb{R} $, which clearly shows $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = c \in \mathbb{R}$.
However, one issue I see is setting $m = x_{0}^{2}$ and $n = x_{0}$ to make general function $h: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} $ where $h(x, y) = mx + ny$, it's not necessarily injective, so I can't just immediately conclude $a_{1} = (\frac{a_{3}}{b_{3}})b_{1}$ and $a_{2} = (\frac{a_{3}}{b_{3}})b_{2}$, if that makes sense.
Kindly if someone could help me here I'd be very grateful. (P.S. hopefully I used the "if" and "iff" arrows correctly there lol. My logic skills are currently a bit rusty).

yeah what you said is right: basically if r is a root of a polynomial, then (x-r) is one if its factors, so the quadratic has to be a(x-r)(x-s) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem

@AlanChung cool thnx! Do you know how I could finish my alternative proof tho?

@AlanChung Also why is the leading coefficient of the polynomial what we multiply in front of the product of all the (x - r) factors? Like why is this equality true $a_n x^n  + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} +\cdots + a_1 x+ a_0 = a_n (x-r_1) (x-r_2) \cdots (x-r_n)$?

it has to be $a_n$ because the that is the correct coefficient of $x^n$ once you multiply out all the factors
